# Is code coverage required for wrapper class to deploy in production if it has only variables declared in it

Tags: code-coverage

```
public class PP_SI_Wrapper {
    public class checkBoxWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled public String que;
        @AuraEnabled public Boolean val;
    }   

    public class empWrapper {

        public Integer intId; 
        public String strName; 
        public String strEmpName ; 
        public String strGloId; 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you run a test method that constructs an instance of this object, you'll see that none of the lines of that object are marked, neither red nor green. So you can conclude that coverage is not needed, as it's not even counted :)

Comment: It means that it will get deployed to production without any test class with 0% code coverage.Can I conclude  like this?

Comment: Yes, that would be a fair conclusion

Comment: Thanks for the update